# Multiple video.js players fail on flash fallback

Tags: javascript, video, flash, video.js

I have the page http://video-stock.co.uk setup with 4 videos, all using video.js. It works fine with chrome etc which use the html5 implementation, but when I view in ie7/8 and the flash fallback, the big video and the first of the small videos are fine, but the other 2 small videos are black, and have no play button overlay, and are unresponsive to clicking, although a right-click does bring up the flash context menu.

I have next to no knowledge of working with flash to play videos, except the odd embed in Wordpress, and I was glad to find Video.js to sort all that out for me. All I can see in the code is that the correct video files seem to be getting sent into flash, but maybe it is because the flash player (.swf) file is being called more than once? Just a novice guess. Any help gratefully received.

Edit, for completeness I set up a test for flash on the page in chrome etc - if you go to http://video-stock.co.uk/?flashdefault you can view the page with all players in flash. It works fine on chrome, ff and even IE7+8. To get the flash default I have used:

_V_.options.techOrder = ["flash", html5, "links"];

I will change the default to that order if I receive no replies from you helpful lot.

Answer (score 0):

After the edit I went to the site in IE without the flashdefault query var and all four players were working.

The only thing I changed was adding preload="auto" to the small videos, and that seems to have been the fix. Although it could have been getting the flash videos into the cache using the flashdefault that fixed it, until some new videos are added we won't find out. To Moderators, should I accept this answer now or wait till I know for sure?